# Multi state survival modelling - medical statistics - separate time to relapse / time to death models or combined with mstate?

Tags: survival, cox-model, competing-risks

I've undertaken a survival analysis of a cohort of cancer patients, all of whom relapse and then the vast majority of whom go on to subsequently die of their disease.

The approach we've taken so far is to undertake two separate analyses, one examining the effects of covariates on time to disease relapse, the other the time from relapse to death or censoring. For both, we have used Cox PH models.

We have been advised on review that the approach may be biased, and that we should consider a multistate model instead. I have implemented this using Hein Putter's `mstate` package, following the helpful tutorial, which prepares data for plugging into `coxph` of the `survival` package.

So in the disease model I specified, patients can move from diagnosis to relapse, and then from relapse to death, but cannot move directly from diagnosis to death (deaths before completion of treatment have been removed).

The results appear broadly the same as the two separate analyses that we did in the first place and the key features remain highly significant. Is it appropriate to use `mstate`, or given that every patient relapses, is the original, separated approach acceptable? I am reassured that the results are so similar, but feel that the intended clinican readership will be more comfortable with the original analysis. Any advice is much appreciated!